# SQL join two tables to give multi array result

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, join, mysqli

I have 2 table `events` and `categories`. `categories` table has 2 columns `id` and `category`. The `event` table contains `category_id`as foreign key of `categories` table.

Now the content of `events` table is given by

```
+------------------------------------------------------+
| id | category_id | event_name | event_date | created |
+------------------------------------------------------+
| 1  |     1       | event 1    | 12-04-2016 |TIMESTAMP|
| 2  |     1       | event 2    | 14-04-2016 |TIMESTAMP|
| 3  |     2       | event 1    | 16-04-2016 |TIMESTAMP|
| 4  |     1       | event 3    | 14-04-2016 |TIMESTAMP|
| 5  |     2       | event 2    | 12-04-2016 |TIMESTAMP|
+------------------------------------------------------+
```

Now what I want to do is to select all rows and produce output in the form

```
=> Category 1
     <> event 1
     <><> 12-04-2016
     <> event 2
     <><> 14-04-2016
     <> event 3
     <><> 14-04-2016
=> Category 2
     <> event 1
     <><> 16-04-2016
     <> event 2
     <><> 12-04-2016
```

How it can be done. I am using `PHP` and `mysqli` and I want to store this information in PHP array so that I could print it anywhere in page using PHP `for` loop or `foreach`

Comment: [With mysqli you have to sort records by hand, while with PDO it's one line](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/mysqli_comparison#array), so the choice is yours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sort the query by category, event name

```
SELECT  categories.category,
        events.event_name

FROM categories

    LEFT JOIN events
    ON events.category_id = categories.id

ORDER BY categories.category, events.event_name
```

then iterate through the result to construct the multi-dimensional array you want:

```
$data = array();

foreach($results as $row){
    $data[$row['category']][$row['event_name']]['event_name'] = $row['event_name'];
    $data[$row['category']][$row['event_name']]['event_date'] = $row['event_date'];
}
```

you can then perform a nested iteration something like this to output:

```
foreach($data as $category => $events){

    echo $category.'<br>';

    foreach($events as $event){
        echo '    <> '.$event['event_name'].'<br>';
        echo '        <> '.$event['event_date'].'<br>';
    }

}
```

Rather than using the event / category names as indexes for the multidimensional array, you could grab the event id and use that instead if the names aren't unique.

Comment: Thank you so much. This is what I wanted. But there is a little issue. The last loop `foreach($evets as $event){ echo '<> '.$event.'</br>'; }` is printing only `<> Array` and not the array element

Comment: I have removed `[skills]` from second last code and now it's working as expected. Thank you

Comment: please see the updated question. I had to add one more column `event_date` to `events` table. Now how could I show the `event date` as well with each event in foreach loop. I have added `$data[$row['category']][$row['event_date']] = $row['event_date'];` just below `$row['event_name']`

Comment: You are creating an array of arrays where the 'category' acts as the index for the category grouping and then the event name acts as the index for the array that holds. Rather than add the line you have, add another index to the end of both lines:     $data[$row['category']][$row['event_name']]['event_name'] = $row['event_name'];     and        $data[$row['category']][$row['event_name']]['event_date'] = $row['event_date'];     then use the named indexes in your nestedr output loop