# SQL join 2 tables and loop through results

Tags: php, mysqli

I have this sql query to get data from 2 tables and join them based on the matching id.

```sql
SELECT   *
FROM     bar_items 
   LEFT JOIN bar_cats ON
         bar_cats.cat_id = bar_items.categories
ORDER BY bar_items.categories,
         bar_items.item_name ASC
```

Which gives me this result

[image]

I am now trying to display these in categories with the category name as the heading for each category.

I have this code so far with the help of an old Stack overflow post: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36458593/sql-join-two-tables-to-give-multi-array-result)

```
    $data = array(); 
foreach($results_lists as $row){
        $data[$row['cat_name']][$row['item_name']]['item_name'] = $row['item_name'];
        $data[$row['cat_name']][$row['item_price']]['item_price'] = $row['item_price'];
        $data[$row['cat_name']][$row['item_image']]['item_image'] = $row['item_image'];
    } foreach($data as $category => $events){

        echo $category.'<br>';

        foreach($events as $event){
            echo '    <> '.$event['item_name'].'<br>';
            echo '        <> '.$event['item_price'].'<br>';
            echo '        <> '.$event['item_image'].'<br>';
        }
```

but it isn't behaving as i need it to and is displaying like this: (note the blank <> lines and further down the list it doesn't display some of the prices even though they are being returned in the query)

```
Beer and Bitter
<> John Smiths
<> 
<> 
<> 
<> 2.50
<> 
<> 
<> 
<> 1556315986_john-smiths.jpg
<> Sam Smiths
<> 
<> 
<> 
<> 2.15
<> 
<> 
<> 
<> 1556316430_Samuel_Smith_Brewery_logo.png
<> Stones
<> 
<> 
<> 
<> 
<> 1556316361_stones.jpg
<> Tetleys
<> 
<> 
<> 
<> 
<> 1556315794_tetleys.jpg
Lager
<> Bud Light
<> 
<> 
<> 
<> 2.50
<> 
<> 
<> 
<> 1556316641_bud-light.png
<> Carling
<> 
<> 
<> 
<> 
<> 1556316497_carling-white-011.png
<> Fosters
<> 
<> 
<> 
<> 
<> 1556316197_fosters.png
Cider
<> Strongbow
<> 
<> 
<> 
<> 2.50
<> 
<> 
<> 
<> 1556316131_Strongbow-Logo-1.png
```

EDIT:
When i print the array i get this:

```
Array
(
    [Beer and Bitter] => Array
        (
            [John Smiths] => Array
                (
                    [item_name] => John Smiths
                )

            [2.50] => Array
                (
                    [item_price] => 2.50
                )

            [1556315986_john-smiths.jpg] => Array
                (
                    [item_image] => 1556315986_john-smiths.jpg
                )

            [Sam Smiths] => Array
                (
                    [item_name] => Sam Smiths
                )

            [2.15] => Array
                (
                    [item_price] => 2.15
                )

            [1556316430_Samuel_Smith_Brewery_logo.png] => Array
                (
                    [item_image] => 1556316430_Samuel_Smith_Brewery_logo.png
                )

            [Stones] => Array
                (
                    [item_name] => Stones
                )

            [1556316361_stones.jpg] => Array
                (
                    [item_image] => 1556316361_stones.jpg
                )

            [Tetleys] => Array
                (
                    [item_name] => Tetleys
                )

            [1556315794_tetleys.jpg] => Array
                (
                    [item_image] => 1556315794_tetleys.jpg
                )

        )

    [Lager] => Array
        (
            [Bud Light] => Array
                (
                    [item_name] => Bud Light
                )

            [2.50] => Array
                (
                    [item_price] => 2.50
                )

            [1556316641_bud-light.png] => Array
                (
                    [item_image] => 1556316641_bud-light.png
                )

            [Carling] => Array
                (
                    [item_name] => Carling
                )

            [1556316497_carling-white-011.png] => Array
                (
                    [item_image] => 1556316497_carling-white-011.png
                )

            [Fosters] => Array
                (
                    [item_name] => Fosters
                )

            [1556316197_fosters.png] => Array
                (
                    [item_image] => 1556316197_fosters.png
                )

        )

    [Cider] => Array
        (
            [Strongbow] => Array
                (
                    [item_name] => Strongbow
                )

            [2.50] => Array
                (
                    [item_price] => 2.50
                )

            [1556316131_Strongbow-Logo-1.png] => Array
                (
                    [item_image] => 1556316131_Strongbow-Logo-1.png
                )

        )

)
```

Where am i going wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: Your code sample is a bit too small for us to mimic, i think maybe you can add a bit more flesh to it or reference to the old StackOverflow link.

Comment: Pictures of code and/or results aren't very useful. Please include a text version in your question.

Comment: @JL2210 sorry, its only the 2nd time posting a question on here,i wasn't sure how to best display the results table so i added the image.

Comment: @HueyMataruse sorry, heres the link to the old post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36458593/sql-join-two-tables-to-give-multi-array-result

Comment: @HueyMataruse i have edited the post and swapped the results image for a code snippet. I'm still not sure how to best display an sql table on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are making life more complex than it needs to be. A simple pass through the resultset should be able to produce the output you are hoping for.

```
$last_cat = null;

foreach($results_lists as $row){
    if ( $last_cat != $row['cat_name'] ) {
        echo $row['cat_name'] . '<br>';
        $last_cat = $row['cat_name'];
    }
    echo '    <> '.$row['item_name'].'<br>';
    echo '        <> '.$row['item_price'].'<br>';
    echo '        <> '.$row['item_image'].'<br>';
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this. You have also taught me a lot with that, i really appreciate it, thank you.

Comment: How could i wrap each category with a div?